# Turning a document into a html form

Tags: html, notepad++

To explain my question more i am going to explain what I'm doing.

I am doing my final project at uni and i don't want to be wasting my time so i want to know if this is possible.

I have a digital forensic report that gets filled out by every investigator and it goes to the case officer to review before carrying on with a case. I want to make that easier by creating a html form that can take the investigators notes and put them in the form for them.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is this currently? Digital report could mean a Word doc, off, etc. Are you hoping to have a web form front end and at some point have the submitted data go to the digital document(s)?

Comment: im working off a word doc.

Answer (score 1):

Building such an application is perfectly possible, and without much fuzz, depending on the scope of your target and if you have already built an web application before.

If you just have to upload documents through a web form, and these will be appended to a final document (may be a PDF which will be rendered on the website) such that the case officer will have less work with reviewing as he can just scroll through, this could already do the job.

Since you are not asking about handwriting recognition or OCR, you do not seem to have any specifications on how to do this yet?
Also do you have a legacy system in which you will have to integrate your application? Or is it a greenfield project where you will also build the 'html forms' by yourself?

But you should get your supervisors do their job and get them to define the applications scope for you properly.

Otherwise this might turn into a neverending story via scope creep when you try to recognize all the handwritings on the documents (not just block lettering), have to support a dozen input formats (not just pdf), ...

Comment: My supervisor is rubbish and i have been going at this on my own and I'm very confused. I tried to change but weren't allowed. I was hoping to build the html form which i have done once before and then try do something different with it so it saves the investigator time on typing it all out. maybe link to a database for cases and do drop down boxes and a few text boxes to discuss the case they are working on. 
If any of this makes sense to you then i might actually be able to do this

Comment: @ShannonGilbert Parsing Office documents = neckshotting yourself. See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html on why this is the case. It's possible, but you need windows server skills (IIS). You should maybe have a look at PDF files, but the situation is comparably dire over there, too. `.csv` files (not .xlsx or .xls!) would be the easiest solution for you, by very far.